# How to create a SSIS packet to import same sheet_name from a bunch of excel files

Tags: ssis

I need to create a SSIS packet to  import same sheet_name from a bunch of excel files. I plan to use Foreach loop to get this done. However, my problem  is I am not  clear how many variables I need to create, but I am aware to do this I need to have one Loop for the files and the other one for the sheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the Sheet_Name is always the same, you should only need 1 variable to store the File Name.

Assuming you are looping through a set of files, the Foreach loop should have a single string variable defined in the "Variable Mappings" section of the properties. This allows you to store the file name you are processing, which will then allow you to dynamically update your Connection Manager's connection string (using an expression). You can then just hard-code the sheet name you want in to Excel Source in your data flow. You many also need to set the data flow property "Delay Validation" to true.

The package will pickup a new file, dynamically update the connection string, and then extract the sheet name you hard coded from each file. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For a step by step process, follow the answer # 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673904/how-can-i-loop-through-multiple-files-and-process-them-using-ssis-package). It has detailed description of what you need to do.