# Creating buffer/ processing multiple files SSIS

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis, integration

I have a watch folder task that monitors a folder. when a file is dropped it runs an execute package task. I have a for loop to make this run all the time. I'm having problems when 2 files are dropped before the execute package task is completed. There could even be 2 files coming in at once. I need to process both files.

Is there a way of doing this, maybe create a buffer to keep track of all files coming in the folder?

This is different from the other question suggested because the files are not already in the folder. They will get moved to the folder at random times, and multiple files can come in at once. What I understood from the other question suggested was that the files are already in the folder when the package is executed. that is not my case.

Comment: Use a foreach loop container in your ssis package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I loop through multiple files and process them using SSIS package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673904/how-can-i-loop-through-multiple-files-and-process-them-using-ssis-package)

Comment: I think it's different because I only process the files that are dropped in the folder. I can have 100 files in the folder, I only want to process the new ones being imported in. plus I can have CSV, XLS and TXT files so their not all the same. I will experiment with for each tomorrow, hopefully it works.

Comment: I ended up following the post suggested and modifying some areas to make it work in my case. I put the for each loop in an infinite for loop. and move the files from a monitoring to processing to done folder at the end of each stage.